# Return value of require statement in ruby

Tags: ruby, require

What does the return value of `require 'lib'` signify in ruby where 'lib' is any library which one wants to include?

For example when I run

```
>>> require 'nmatrix'
```

I get `False` as the return value. What does it mean?

Comment: What's the reason for down vote?

Comment: I suppose for not checking the documentation before asking.

Comment: One of the guidelines on [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is `Search, and research` - which can mean that do  your home work to find an answer.  Now, at the time of this comment, there are two answers to this question - I suggest you to read the documentation of `require` method - http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require and answer for yourself whether any of those answers did provide any more details than what is already available in documentation.

Comment: Okay. Won't happen again I promise. Should I delete this question now or leave it?

Comment: I would like to say Don't delete question, because I would help for new developer to learn from, how to ask question.

Comment: See, the interesting thing is, when you'e new to a language, and you don't yet know all the URLs to visit to see these things (i.e. ruby-doc.org) you end up doing a Google search, and all your lovely "official" Ruby documentation never feature in the top results, which leaves one feeling a little lost. Hence, you come to forums like this looking for assistance, only to be assailed by know-it-alls. Let me guess, all of you just magically assimilated all knowledge of the language through osmosis, right???? Yes, I expect downvotes, etc., but you all suck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[require](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/require) returns `false` if the given library has already been loaded.

```
>> require 'time'
=> true # time.rb was successfully loaded
>> require 'time' 
=> false # time.rb was already found in-memory, it won't be loaded again
```

Requiring an already loaded library has no effect in Ruby. The return flag is there to provide you information. A `false` result translates to: "*you've asked me to load this library but it is already in memory and I'm not going to load it again*".

On the other hand you have [**load**](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/load), which will load and execute the contents of a file-name **every time** it is called.

Answer (score 1):

It means, that the library already loaded.

> [`require`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/require) 
>   Loads the given name, returning true if successful and false if the
>   feature is already loaded.

```
>> val = require 'set'
=> true
>> val_two = require 'set'
=> false
>> val
=> true
>> val_two
=> false
```